# I want to write an Async JSON contacts which will overwrite the content of my data.json file

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have written the file `contact.js` using [jsonfile.writeFile.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonfile#writefile-filename-options-callback)

Here's my contact.js code:

```
var Contact = {}
Contact.saveContacts=function(contacts,done){
var jsonfile = require('jsonfile')
jsonfile.writeFile('data.json',contacts, done, function(err){
done(err)
})
}
module.exports=Contact
```

Here's test.js

```
var contacts = [ { name: "John Smith", number: "604-123-9090" } ]
Contact.saveContacts(contacts, function(err) {
console.log('success')
  })
```

I get the following error:

> Error: Contact.saveContacts did not write any data or the written data    is incorrect.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I solve the solution like this way.I change the `contact.js` file like this way.

```
 var Contact = {}
 Contact.saveContacts=function(contacts,done){
 var jsonfile = require('jsonfile')
 jsonfile.writeFile('data.json',contacts,function(err){
 done(err)
 })
 }

 module.exports=Contact
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your contact.js like below:

```
Contact.saveContacts = function(contacts, done) {
var jsonfile = require('jsonfile');

jsonfile.writeFile('data.json', contacts, done);
```

}

And your test.js like you wrote.

I hope I've helped.

Comment: I copied your source code to try to simulate your situation, but I can't. I did in Ubuntu and Windows the same thing, two situations I could write the file. Did you try to create another directory with another files and run?